# HTML Table with vertically rotated headers on the left side

Tags: html, grid, css-tables

I'm trying to create a html table to populate with some data that looks like the image below. I'm able to rotate the text with simple css but having trouble figuring out how to organize the sub rows/columns. Is this possible with html/css tables or at least grid?

[image: really ugly table with headers rotated on the side]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this b treating each  tag as it's own row and building the data on them individually.

```
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class="rotate">Header Text</td>
      <td class="rotate pole">SubHeader Text 1</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul class="no-ul-style">
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="rotate pole">SubHeader Text 2</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul class="no-ul-style">
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rotate pole">SubHeader Text 3</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul class="no-ul-style">
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rotate pole">SubHeader Text 4</td>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
          <li>text text text text text text text text</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ul class="no-ul-style">
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
          <li>6</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        6
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Yep ! This is how I would have done it too,good job figuring it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can with a simple table and a CSS property : `transform: rotate()`, see:

```css
table {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-90deg)
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="rotate" rowspan="2">
      Rotated cell
    </td>
    <td>
      Normal cell
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Normal cell
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, rotating the text on table hasn't been my problem so far (sorry for not being clear about that). I'm more so trying to figure out how to nest all of the cells under these rotated column style rows. Thanks for your time.